# How many elements are there in this quotient ring?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ideals, finite-rings

So we are having this undergraduate course in my department of commutative algebra and there is a problem sheet that we have to submit. The second problem goes like this:

**Let $R$ be the ring $R=\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt2]=\{a+b\sqrt2:a,b\in\mathbb{Z}\}$ and let $J=17R\subseteq R.$ How many elements are there in the quotient ring $R/J$? Is $J$ a prime ideal?**

Now, I know a theorem that states that $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt n]/p\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt n]$ (p: prime) is a field (hence $p\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt n]$ is a maximal and therefore a prime ideal) if and only if there is no $a\in\mathbb{Z}$ such that $$a^2\equiv n\mod p$$ and in that case, $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt n]/p\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt n]$ has $p^2$ elements.

In my case the previous theorem does not work because for $6\in\mathbb{Z}$ I got $6^2\equiv 2\mod 17$ so am a bit confused.

ps. This is my first post, so accept my apologies for any mistakes i've made.

ps2. Sorry for my english.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is how I look at such problems. First of all, $\Bbb Z[\sqrt{2}]\cong \Bbb Z[x]/(x^2-2)$.

Then using isomorphism theorems, $\Bbb Z[\sqrt{2}]/(17)\cong \Bbb Z[x]/(x^2-2,17)\cong(\Bbb Z/(17))[x]/(x^2-2)=\Bbb F_{17}[x]/(x^2-2)$.

(I'm taking some liberties with the notation: the parenthesis around elements denote the ideal generated in the ring in context. That's why even though the $(17)$ all look alike, they're actually different sets as they are generated in their respective rings.)

So the question amounts to figuring out the structure of $\Bbb F_{17}[x]/(x^2-2)$, but quotients of polynomial rings over fields are pretty easy to analyze. The ideal $(x^2-2)$ is going to be prime iff $x^2-2$ is irreducible over $\Bbb F_{17}$, but you'll discover quickly that it has two distinct roots over this field, and is reducible.

Given the two roots $\alpha,\beta$, the Chinese remainder theorem says that $\Bbb F_{17}[x]/(x^2-2)\cong \Bbb F_{17}[x]/(x-\alpha)\times \Bbb F_{17}[x]/(x-\beta)\cong \Bbb F_{17}\times \Bbb F_{17}$, so the ring has $289$ elements.

Comment: I have one confusion in the last line: I understand that the ideals $(x-a)$ and $(x-b)$ are comaximal (i.e., their sum equals $F_{17}[x]$). Applying CRT, the LHS should be $F_{17}[x]/K,$ where $K=(x-a)\cap (x-b)=\color{blue}{\rm \, product\, of \, ideals\, (x-a)\, and\, (x-b)}$. Equality to the blue colored part is true by comaximality. But I'm having hard time understanding why $K=(x^2-2)$ (parentheses denoting ideals here). Can you please explain that? Thanks.

Comment: Because $\alpha$ and $\beta$ were chosen as being the two distinct roots of $2$ in $\mathbb F_{17}$.

Comment: Using the distinction, I understand that since $a-b=a-x+x-b\in (x-a)+(y-b)$, $1$ is also in the sum as $a-b$ being non zero is a unit. But in general, I believe that it is not true that $(pq)=(p)(q)$ (I understand that $(pq)\subset (p)(q)$). So taking $p=x-\alpha, q=x-\beta$, why is LHS in the last line in the answer the way it is? That's what I'm having difficulty understanding. Shouldn't there have been $(x-a)(x-b)$ instead of $(x^2-2)$ (here parentheses represent ideals)?

Comment: @Koro In a commutative ring, it is indeed true that $(a)(b)=(ab)$, so your concerns arising after "but in general" are not an issue.  If $x$ is in $(p)$ and $y$ is in $(q)$ then obviously $xy$ is a multiple of $pq$, proving the reverse containment.

Comment: I understand that $(p)(q):=\{\sum_{i=1}^n p_iq_i: p_i\in (p), q_i\in (q), n\in \mathbb N\}$ so shouldn't one start with: suppose $\sum_{i=1}^np_iq_i\in (p)(q)$ and then show that $\sum_{i=1}^np_iq_i\in (pq)$? I think I should use induction to establish the reverse containment. Is my understanding correct? Thanks.

Comment: @Koro From your first equality, just factor out all the common multiples of $p$ and $q$ from the $p_iq_i$ terms.  Yes, perhaps you would formally need to use induction.  I prefer to think of it is as "if the generators of an ideal $A$ are in an ideal $B$, then all of $A$ is in $B$." The generators of $(p)(q)$ are simply the pairwise products.

Comment: I think I understood now. Thank you so much. :-)

Answer (score 5):

You can do it by hand very easily: two elements $a+b\sqrt{2}$ and $c+d\sqrt{2}$ lie in the same coset iff their difference belongs to $17R$. Since $17R=\{17x+17y\sqrt{2}\colon x,y\in \mathbb Z\}$, you have that $a+b\sqrt{2}$ and $c+d\sqrt{2}$ lie in the same coset iff $a\equiv b\bmod 17$ and $c\equiv d\bmod 17$. So you see that $R/17R$ has $17^2$ elements and it is not a field for the reason you pointed out. In fact, $R/17R$ is isomorphic as a ring to $\mathbb F_{17}\times \mathbb F_{17}$.

Answer (score 1):

We have $$(5-2\sqrt{2} )\cdot (5+2\sqrt{2} )=17 \in J$$ but $5-2\sqrt{2}\notin J$ and $5+2\sqrt{2}\notin J$ hence $J$ is not prime ideal.

Comment: OP already has $\ 17\mid 6^2-\sqrt{2}^2 = (6-\sqrt 2)(6+\sqrt 2)\ \ $